# Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError from org/jfree/chart?

Tags: java, applet, classpath

I am trying to make a simple applet that displays a 3D pie chart, but am getting a

```
RuntimeException (`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel`)
```

I've been running in circles trying to find out why, thinking that it may be a problem with the applet being able to read the 3rd party libraries I used.  It works fine in NetBeans, but in the browser I keep getting the error.  Any clue what I did wrong?  Code below:

HTML:

```html
<APPLET codebase="classes" code="CyberThreatApplet/CyberThreatApplet.class" 
    archive="jfreechart-1.0.19.jar,jcommon-1.0.23.jar" width=350 height=200>
</APPLET>
```

Java:

```
package CyberThreatApplet;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlot3D;
import org.jfree.data.general.*;
import org.jfree.util.Rotation;

public class CyberThreatApplet extends JApplet

{

@Override
public void init()
{
    CreateChart("Cyber Attack Pie Chart","Motivations Behind Cyber Attacks - May 2013");
}

private void CreateChart(String appTitle, String chartTitle)

{
    PieDataset dataset = createDataset();
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset,chartTitle);
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,300));
    add(chartPanel);
}

private PieDataset createDataset()

{
    DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();
    result.setValue("Cybercrime",46);
    result.setValue("Hacktivism",36);
    result.setValue("Cyber Espionage",9);
    result.setValue("Cyber Warfare",9);
    return result;
}

private JFreeChart createChart(PieDataset dataset,String title)

{
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(title,dataset,true,true,false);
    PiePlot3D plot = (PiePlot3D)chart.getPlot();
    plot.setStartAngle(90);
    plot.setDirection(Rotation.CLOCKWISE);
    plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.75f);
    return chart;
}

}
```

Comment: How do you use in HTML?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add - just updated

Comment: I changed the two line `archive attribute` to a single line while formatting.  It it two lines in the original HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that `jfreechart-1.0.19.jar` (and all other jars) are located in the `classes` directory relative to the HTML file

Comment: Where in the folder should I save the .jar files?

Comment: For some reason it's still not working...will try and restart my computer and see if that fixes things.

Comment: I put the jar files in both the classes folder and in the folder with the html file (just in case).  Not sure if making copies of the files messes anything up.

Comment: There's no need to have them in the same location as the HTML file since youre specifying the codebase...